# VSCode Powerline symbols overlap in integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, powerline

In the VSCode integrated terminal, my powerline fonts appear to overlap like this:

[image]

They should look like this:

[image]

Weirdly if I change the font size or letter spacing to a value and then back again, the symbols look as they should:

[image]

The font I am using is "MesloLGM Nerd Font Mono" and I'm seeing the issue in both Windows and Linux. MesloLGM Nerd Font is typically the recommended font from what I've seen in discussions/GitHub issues.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

**Edit**: It seems to be fixed in 1.56 :)